# Extract dates in various formats from free text string in excel

Tags: excel

I'm struggling with extracting dates from a free text field in Excel where the date could be in any number of formats due to human input.

Some examples of the entries are below but essentially they could be 30/6, 30/06, 30th June, 30/6/21, 30/06/21, 30/06/2021, 30-6, 30th, 30-06, tomorrow!

Alright; I probably can't do much about that last one and I can pull the date from the others if I know the format but I'm looking for something that would handle any and all of the permutations.

Example Data

| Column A |
| --- |
| Empire still haven't repaired the roof. Waiting on Empire to waterproof the roof then I can patch up the ceiling in 611. ETA 30/06/2021 |
| ETA 11/6/21 |
| floor boards need replaced |
| 22/6/21 awaiting parts |
| have sanded the filler that was in the war and refilled ready for or sanding again |
| new bathroom floor to replace. need to source materials and have time to do job. full bathroom sub floor to replace. ETA 29/06 |
| Engineer attended and found E122 error, reset and tested but fault still present. New EVA probe required. Part to be sent to site. |
| new toilet handle ordered. ETA 28th June |
| TV on order |
| refer to Colin Warner for further works and required parts |
| 28/6 awaiting underlay |
| leak in room 315 fixed. room 215 will need a week to dry. ETA 30th June. |
| 10 July |
| ceiling too wet to carry out any work. eta 5-07-2021 |

I know it's a big ask but if you know of a formula or VBA UDF that can handle all of those then I'd be eternally grateful.

Comment: thanks [@chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445425/chris-neilsen)

Comment: Maybe your best bet is a UDF where you try to use a regular expression to cover most of your common date formats. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/GhXh3Q/1) is an example.

Comment: @JvdV that is **FAB** thanks so much - not sure how to pop it into a UDF though - any pointers? I know how to create a UDF, just unsure how to fit that regex expression into it :o(